# How to find out the number of transmitted/received bytes for a socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, benchmarking

For benchmarking I am currently looking for a way to benchmark some TCP-Connections that seem to have problems. For this I would like to log some performance indicators while the program is running. I am already logging the time for each operation, however this just tells me the transmission takes way too long for the use case.

What I would need is a simple way to track the number of bytes read/written at periodic intervals. Normally I would just add the benchmarking manually, but the socket is used in a library so I cannot instrument the read/write calls easily. My guess would be that there is some readily available method provided by linux, that could do this, but I cannot find it.

I already looked at the possibilities of `getsockopt()` with the `TCP_INFO` flag, but from the documentation I can only see how to get the window size etc. from this, but not the number of bytes read/written.

Is there any way to get this information from Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Try `tcpdump`, define a filter that will listen only on the port/address that your program is communicating on and sum up the printed length attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that today the most interesting way of doing this is injecting a KProbe at  `tcp_sendmsg` (for transmit) and `tcp_cleanup_rbuf`(for receive) using eBPF.

For an example (and working code), check out the `tcptop` tool from the [BCC project](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc): https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcptop.py#L160

From the referenced code, ignoring IPV6 is looks like this:

```
int kprobe__tcp_sendmsg(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sock *sk,
    struct msghdr *msg, size_t size)
{
    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    u16 dport = 0, family = sk->__sk_common.skc_family;
    u64 *val, zero = 0;

    if (family !=  AF_INET) {
      return 0;
    }

    struct ipv4_key_t ipv4_key = {.pid = pid};

    ipv4_key.saddr = sk->__sk_common.skc_rcv_saddr;
    ipv4_key.daddr = sk->__sk_common.skc_daddr;
    ipv4_key.lport = sk->__sk_common.skc_num;

    dport = sk->__sk_common.skc_dport;
    ipv4_key.dport = ntohs(dport);

    // pick the entry in the map
    val = ipv4_send_bytes.lookup_or_init(&ipv4_key, &zero);

    // write to the entry in the map
    (*val) += size;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using [Kernel Probes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) you can "*break into*" kernel/system calls on the fly and read/log their arguments. Doing this for `read()`/`recv*()` and/or `write()`/`send*()` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably look at the contents of `/proc/net/tcp` file to read some of the **recv/send statistics**  `netstat` utility on most Linux systems does the same thing but in a cleaner way.

In you program, parse this file at various points of time to gather information on bytes received/sent on a socket, though i am not sure if it can map the bytes for a specific TCP socket.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain if you're looking at sockets or need to calculate the whole amount of RX/TX bytes on a given interface.  I needed to address the latter problem, whipped up the following script that might be useful to you:

```
while true; do MARKER=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "[RT]X bytes" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 7-); sleep 10; NEWMARKER=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "[RT]X bytes" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 7-); expr ${NEWMARKER} - ${MARKER}; set $MARKER=$NEWMARKER; done
```

Note that for myself the number of received bytes was really the only important value, use as template to extract sent bytes if required.

Change the sleep value to whatever interval you require (measured in seconds), redirect to file if needed.